# How to transfer an element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this function that calls upon a modal

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {

// Get textfield
var textfield = $('#txt1');

// Get value
var input = textfield.val();

// Check if the value is already in the database
var json = textfield.data('json');
if (itemExists(input, json)) {
    // Stuff
} else {
    $('#modalAddText').append('X does not exist');
    $('#myModal').modal();
}

});
```

Then this to check if the user clicked "OK"

```
$('#modalOk').click(function () {
    insertItem(itemone, itemtwo);
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

So the problem is I don't have access to the textfield in the first function anymore, so how can I get/keep access to it?

And I can't just do `$('#txt1');` because I have multiple txtfields

So can I somehow transfer the `textfield` variable?

Comment: I would think: declare `textfield` outside the click functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `textfield` in outer scope.

That is:

```
var textfield = $('#txt1');

$('#btn1').click(function () {
 ... // textfield is achievable 
});

$('#modalOk').click(function () {
 ... // textfield is achievable
});
```

Comment: `var` makes it local. All JavaScript variables are global by default. Though taking it out should solve the problem.

Comment: Won't necessarily be `global`, will just be in scope accessible to both methods